# Regular Expression that matches when any string has minimum three characters, and + signs are surrounded by minimum three characters

Tags: regex

I wanted to create regex expression that only matches when any string has three or more character and if any + sign in the string then after and before + sign it must be minimum three characters required,

I have created one regex it fulfills me all requirement except one that before first + sign must be minimum three characters but it matches with less character

this is my current regex: `(\+[a-z0-9]{3}|[a-z0-9]{0,3})$`

`ab+abx` this string should not match but it matched in my regex

Example:

### Valid Strings:

```
sss
sdfsgdf
4534534
dfs34543
sdafds+3232+sfdsafd
qwe+sdf
234+567
cvb+243
```

### Invalid Strings:

```
a
aa
a+
aa+
+aa
+a
a+a
aa+aa
aaa+a
```

Comment: Looks like `[a-z0-9]{3}$` is enough, see https://regex101.com/r/wjYPnW/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^[^+\n]{3,}(?:\+[^+\n]{3,})*$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `[^+\n]{3,}` - This ensures it matches any characters except `+` and newline, `\n` you can actually remove if the input you're trying to match doesn't contain any newlines and `{3,}` allows it to match at least three and more characters
- `(?:\+[^+\n]{3,})*` - This part further allows matching of a `+` character then further separated by at least three or more characters and whole of it zero or more times to keep appearance of `+` character optional
- `$` - End of input

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhQDbO/1)**

**Edit: Updating solution where a space does not participate in counting the number of characters in either side of `+` where minimum number of character required were three**

You can use this regex to ignore counting spaces within the text,

```
^(?:[^+\n ] *){3,}(?:\+ *(?:[^+\n ] *){3,})*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhQDbO/4)**

Also, in case you're dealing with only alphanumeric text, you can use this simpler and easier to maintain regex,

```
^(?:[a-z0-9] *){3,}(?:\+ *(?:[a-z0-9] *){3,})*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhQDbO/3)**

Comment: while checking for three characters before and after of + symbol it should not allowed  space e.g. jc + fjewif + fjeie this string should not be match because here jc only two characters so

Comment: @HiteshKansagara: Ok thats easy. Just change `\n` to `\s`. [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhQDbO/2)

Comment: jc f+ fjewif + fjeie this string should be match

Comment: ok, got it, you don't want to count space as a character and ignore it. Lemme tweak my regex for allowing that.

Comment: @HiteshKansagara: You can use this regex [`^(?:[^+\n ] *){3,}(?:\+ *(?:[^+\n ] *){3,})*$`](https://regex101.com/r/nhQDbO/4) and more simply [this](https://regex101.com/r/nhQDbO/3) if allowed characters are only alphanumeric

Comment: Glad to help again :) Let me know if you further have any queries or issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could repeat 0+ times matching 3 or more times what is listed in the character class `[a-z0-9]` preceded by a plus sign:

```
^[a-z0-9]{3,}(?:\+[a-z0-9]{3,})*$
```

That will match:

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z0-9]{3,}` Match 3+ times what is listed in the character class
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\+[a-z0-9]{3,}` Match `+` sign followed by matching 3+ times what is listed in the character class
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string